# C++ code for Microsoft Kinect - trying to dynamically allocate array of target positions

Tags: c++, arrays, kinect, dynamic-arrays

So I'm trying to modify the Kinect BodyBasicsD2D code so that a fixed number of "target positions" appear on the screen (as ellipses) for the user to move his hand toward. I'm having trouble creating the initial target positions.

This is my code in the header file for the allocation of the array of target positions (these are a public field of the CBodyBasics class, already built into the original BodyToBasics program):

```
D2D1_POINT_2F*  targetPositions = NULL;
int numTargets = 3;
```

Then I have a function "GenerateTargetPositions" which is supposed to generate 3, in this case, target positions to be passed into the "DrawTargetPositions" function.

```
void CBodyBasics::GenerateTargetPositions(D2D1_POINT_2F * targetPositions, int numTargets)
{
    targetPositions = new D2D1_POINT_2F[numTargets];
    RECT rct;
    GetClientRect(GetDlgItem(m_hWnd, IDC_VIDEOVIEW), &rct);
    int width = rct.right;
    int height = rct.bottom;
    FLOAT x;
    FLOAT y;
    D2D1_POINT_2F tempPoint;

    for (int i = 0; i < numTargets; i++) {
        x = 1.0f*i*width / numTargets;
        y = 1.0f*i*height / numTargets;
        tempPoint = D2D1::Point2F(x, y);
        targetPositions[i] = tempPoint;
    }

}
```

My DrawTargetPositions function is:

```
void CBodyBasics::DrawTargetPositions(D2D1_POINT_2F * targetPositions, int numTargets)
{
    D2D1_ELLIPSE ellipse;
    for (int i = 0; i < numTargets; i++) 
    {
        ellipse = D2D1::Ellipse(targetPositions[i], 50.f, 50.f);
        m_pRenderTarget->FillEllipse(ellipse, m_pSilverBrush);
    }
}
```

When I try to run my code, I get the error that both "targetPositions" and "targetPositions[i]" is NULL (and thus my GenerateTargetPositions function must not be working properly). I believe that targetPositions[i] is a struct (a point with x and y values) so I am wondering if this may be the reason for my errors.

I call GenerateTargetPositions and DrawTargetPositions before the main "while" loop in my code so that each function is not being called on each iteration (there are many iterations of through the while loop because this is an interactive Microsoft Kinect, recording one's movements).

Any suggestions and advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: Passing `D2D1_POINT_2F * targetPositions` and then `targetPositions = new D2D1_POINT_2F[numTargets];` does not do what you think it does. However you should be using `std::vector` or `std::array` anyway

Comment: @UnholySheep thanks! And I have 
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

included at the top of my file. do you know how i might fix this problem? I tried statically allocating the array too without much further luck

Comment: The simplest (but definitely not best) fix would be to change `GenerateTargetPositions(D2D1_POINT_2F * targetPositions, int numTargets)` to `GenerateTargetPositions(D2D1_POINT_2F *& targetPositions, int numTargets)` (the `&` would make sure you actually modify the passed in pointer). You should really look into `std::vector` and `std::array` though (and not sure what you mean by *"statically allocating the array too without much further luck"* - you'd need to post the actual code *after* trying to debug it yourself)